# One of two partitions doesn't mount (macOS 10.13.6)

Tags: hard-drive, high-sierra, partition, mount

I have a 2TB HDD with 2 partitions:

- a 1.8TB in HFS to work with
- a small one of 200GB in FAT32 to exchange with PC

2 days ago, the HFS partition failed to mount, while the second partition is working fine.

What I've tried so far:

- I tried to mount in Disk Utility, nothing happened.
- I succeeded in mounting the 1.8TB partition once using Terminal and the
  `diskutil mount` command. But now it doesn't mount anymore.  The
  second partition (FAT32) doesn't unmount, even with the `force unmount` command.

I tried to run `First Aid`. This is the output:

- Partition 1 (HFS): HFS 2 3516326257 3516326256

> ```
> Warning: Bad starting sector (CHS and LBA
>    don't match) Warning:    number of heads/cylinder mismatches 255
>    (FAT) != 1 (HD) Warning:    number of sectors per track mismatches 32
>    (FAT) != 1 (HD)
> ```

- Partition 2 (FAT32): FAT32 3516326259 3907029167  390702909 [LACIE SHARE]

> Warning: Bad starting sector (CHS and LBA don't match) No partition
> is bootable"

**Is there anything I can do?**

P.S:
Problem solved, I runned the First Aid in recovery mode for both the partitions, then I turned the computer back on and the partition was mounted. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sometimes running first aid multiples times and in recovery mode yields result. Can you try that?